# Byte array to Image and show in HTML

Tags: java, html

I saved the user image to the database in binary. I can get the data back using `user.getImage()`. How do I transform it back to a image and display it in `<img>` ??

```
<%
//getting mysql data
User user = (User) iterator.next();
byte[] image = user.getImage();
%>
```

HTML

```
<td><img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src=""> </td>
```

Comment: Either save it somewhere (if the request and image getting is in the HTML request)  and point to the saved image OR convert it to DATA-URI

Comment: Why do I need to save the image again if it's the data base?

Comment: I just want to show on that <img tag

Comment: So `src="myJavaProcessThatDoesgetImage"`

Comment: You can save the image on the filesystem and only keep the filename on the database, or save the image as a bite[] on the database and convert it to base64 data-uri and use that as the image src